# How to fix custom 404 page not working in NextJS

Tags: next.js

I got stuck with custom 404 error page. I have created 404.js in pages folder following instruction in NextJS docs but it still uses default page in NextJS. Does anyone know this issue? Thank in advance.

Dependency:

"next": "9.2.2"

next.config.js just has env config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [their blog post about Next.js 9.3](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3#automatic-static-optimization-for-404)

> This feature is **fully backwards compatible** so if you currently have a custom `pages/_error.js` it will continue to be used for the 404 page until you add `pages/404.js`.

`pages/404.js` is **available starting from Next.js 9.3**, either you can upgrade your dependency from 9.2.2 to 9.3 or use `pages/_error.js` stated as [Documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page#customizing-the-error-page).